# Credit Memo Subtotal Mismatch magento 2.2.8

Tags: email, email-templates, creditmemo, subtotal, magento2.2.8

**I'm Trying To change Subtotal For The item In Credit Memo Email**

[image]

**Product Price:- 4.99**

I am creating a `credit memo` for **10 product** but **Subtotal** is a mismatch

The **grand total** is correct.

how can I change `subtotal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I Don't Know Its Magento Functionality Or Issue But Found The Solution :-**

> **Just Copy This File In Theme**
>
> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/creditmemo/default.phtml

**In Line No. 34**

> In This Line Print Item Ordered Total

**From :-**

```
$block->getItemPrice($_item->getOrderItem())
```

**To :-**

```
$block->getItemPrice($_item)
```

Comment: Works in first go. Thanks

Comment: Most Welcome.. @Sukumar Gorai